# Can we rewrite the MediaCodec API in C?

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, encode, android-mediacodec

I am thinking about using hardware encoding on my Nexus Tablet, since I need to use some video algorithm, I want to make it C.

There is a native-media sample in `Google NDK which support native use of OMX` to do the decode job. But it seems that it doesn't support encode yet. Now we have the MediaCodec API, which can provide the hardware encode. I check the [java file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/media/java/android/media/MediaCodec.java), it seems that most of it function is written in C. So I am wondering if this is possible:

1)find the corresponding C files
2)compile these C file into **.so** file
3)write a **.cpp** file according to the **MediaCodec.java** file, this **.cpp** file will call the functions in the .so file and perform the similar function as **MediaCodec.java**.

Then I can do the encode in C.

Is that right? And is that possible? If that possible, do i need to modify the system on my tablet?

Thank you!

Comment: `MediaCodec` is written in C++, with a very thin Java wrapper around it.  I don't believe the C++ `MediaCodec` is exposed in the NDK though.  You could certainly write a thin C++ wrapper to go around it.  It might make more sense to do all of the higher-level stuff in Java and just write native functions for the parts that need to be fast (e.g. anything that touches every pixel in the image).

Comment: @fadden Thank you! So to use that native function, I need to compile the corresponding source code files into .so file, right? (Since it is not exposed in NDK)